# VBA- Border line a cell based on a different cell's value

Tags: excel

How do I write a VBA macro that for every "Carry Over" I input in column E, I want to border the corresponding B cell in Red. And this is across the worksheet.

For e.g, in the picture below, everytime I change the word "Done" to "Carry Over" in column E, I need the corresponding B cell to be bordered in Red.

[image]

In the picture below, the rule instructs Excel to highlight ever matching cell in B with the condition $E3 = "Carry Over" and there are some cells that are incorrectly painted.

This is the conditional rule

[image]

Comment: Why not use Conditional Formatting?  From your previous questions, don't you already have it to change the color of the text?

Comment: Well, I thought the conditional formatting worked but it is coloring different cells weirdly. See attached screen-grab of the conditional formatting rule. It does not seem to be working. Besides, I will have several tables like the one above and every time there is a change of value in column E to "Carry Over", I want the cell in B to change its color.

Comment: You need to change the formula to reference the top cell of the range equal to the Applies To: `=$E1="Carry Over"`

Comment: That did it! Now, if I wanted the E column cell that has "Carry Over" to also be highlighted, what would I do?

Comment: make your applies to: `=$B:$B,$E:$E`

Comment: @ Scott Craner - I have an additional question. I have added comments w/ screen grabs under 12/6/2019 above. Can you help, please?

Comment: That is a new question and should have a new post not editing this one.

Comment: Alright, will create a new question. Did not want to duplicate. Apologies.